# Django: Request data is missing while calling view from view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am calling view from another view in for loop.
First time, view is processed properly but next time request object is empty.

```
for index, component in enumerate(components_list):
    AggregateData.as_view()(request._request, nquery=index)
```

Here for second iteration request object is empty (request is `<QueryDict: {}>`).
Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: you can make a deep copy of request object and pass it with every iteration

Answer (score 0):

As @ruddra said in the comment you can use `deepcopy` like below

```py
import copy

for index, component in enumerate(components_list):
    AggregateData.as_view()(copy.deepcopy(request), nquery=index)
```